# Airflow web server starts without Gunicorn and is not accessible

Tags: webserver, gunicorn, airflow

I'm using Airflow 1.9 and it was working fine for over 2 months but somehow now I am not able to start `airflow webserver` on Gunicorn.

```
nohup airflow webserver $* > webserver_new.logs &
```

just starts the web server process but log does not contain any mention of Gunicorn. The UI is not accessible. I have checked that the environment variable `$AIRFLOW_HOME` points to the correct path.

Also when the web server is being started it doesn't create a webserver-pid file in `$AIRFLOW_HOME`.

When I uninstall Gunicorn and start the Airflow web server I do not get any error but without Gunicorn the UI is not accessible. Basically it behaves the same whether gunicorn is present or not.

#### Environment

I use a Python 2.7 `virtualenv` on a CentOS box. Few other developers updated some Python packages like `pyhive`, `thrift` and `six`. I have uninstalled all those and uninstalled Airflow using `pip` (and installed back again).

#### Log contents

The web server logs do not contain any mention of Gunicorn and the do not contain any other error when started from the command line. The DAGs are running but the UI was still down.

```
[2018-02-21 14:13:36,082] {default_celery.py:41} WARNING - Celery Executor will run without SSL
```

#### Additional observation

After a manual start of Gunicorn I found that the workers are getting timed out as soon as they are created.

Comment: Please describe your environment a bit more: Operating system, python version etc.. ... Any changes in environment you did between it working/not working? + please post any possible error log. I'm asking because I experienced when running under WSL on Win10 I had version 1.8.2 working. When installing 1.9.0 it didn't. And when Win 10 then got upgraded from ver 1703 to 1709 fixes to WSL Ubuntu made v1.9.0 work.

Comment: I use a pyhton 2.7 virtual env on a cent OS box. Few other developers updated some python packages like pyhive, thrift and six. I have uninstalled all those and uninstalled airflow using pip and installed back again.  The webserver logs do not contain any mention of gunicorn and does not contain an other error when started from command line.   The dags are running in the morning but UI was still down.                                                                    
[2018-02-21 14:13:36,082] {default_celery.py:41} WARNING - Celery Executor will run without SSL

Comment: after manual start of gunicorn for airflow I found that gunicorn workers are getting timed out  as soon as they are created

Comment: Ah OK. Completely different than my issue then. AFAIK the root cause of mine was simply that the previous Win10 WSL Ubuntu didn't have proper `/proc/stat/<whatever>` support. I suggest you edit your - extra info into your question. Better Q&A content quality then. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I found out that the problem was a dag which had a for loop to generate dynamic tasks(all tasks were dyanmic) but the task ids were same for each iteration, I removed that dag and the webserver came back like charm.

Comment: stuck for two hour with similar kind of issue... thanks for posting the answer :)